# Inserting JSON Subobject into existing JSON

Tags: java, json

I get JSON back from a web service call that looks like this:

```
{
  results : 
    {
     seg: {
        segName: whatever,
        segType: atest,
        var: [
            {field1: value1,
             field2: value2,
             field3: value3},
            {field1: value4,
             field2: value5,
             field3: value6}
            ]
          }
     }
}
```

I am using the net.sf.json package in Java. I create a JSON object from this result.

I would like to manually add another entry (JSONObject) to the array "var".

Other than deconstructing the object all the way down to the JSONArray "var", and then rebuilding it, is there a way to just insert another entry into var?

I tried accumulate("var", new JSONObject(...)); but that stuck the new object at the same level as "seg" in the "results" section.

Comment: You can edit the text or just get json object... It's not as intensive as you think there's generally no point to avoid getting the obj

Comment: My fault, I had to fat finger the json into this question because my dev box isn't connected to the Internet.  I edited the post to add the commas. I'd like to avoid hand-jamming the text of the new entry into the var area of the text version of the JSON.  I was hoping there was an elegant solution that allows me to add a JSONObject to the JSONArray called "var".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call accumulate at the level you want the new object inserted.

If you drill down to the "seg" level, and accumulate the new object there, you'll add the new entry to the "var" array.

e.g.

```
String json = // your input JSON string here
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
obj.getJSONObject("results")
   .getJSONObject("seg")
   .accumulate("var", new JSONObject("{field1 : value7, field2: value8, field3: value9}"));
System.out.println(obj);
```

gives

```
{"results":{"seg":{"var":[{"field3":"value3","field2":"value2","field1":"value1"},{"field3":"value6","field2":"value5","field1":"value4"},{"field3":"value9","field2":"value8","field1":"value7"}],"segType":"atest","segName":"whatever"}}}
```

Comment: Why is the result in a "wrong" order? Is there a possibilty to avoid this?

Comment: This works great! Thanks!  

Side note: If you want to add the new element in a particular spot (say at the beginning) use: 

obj.getJSONObject("results").getJSONObject("seg").getJSONArray("var").add(0, newJSONObject("{field1:value1, field2:value2,field3:value3}"));